# How to copy files from clipboard with AppleScript?

Tags: macos, shell, copy, applescript, symlink

I have this shell script which resolves a symbolic link (symlink) to a folder and copies it to the current working directory:

```
cp -R `grealpath /some/dir/symlink_to_folder` .
```

The command `grealpath` just resolves a symbolic link when **coreutils** are installed on Mac OS X.

My question is: What would be the equivalent as an AppleScript? The workflow would be ideally like this: Copy one or more symbolic link-folders in Finder to the clipboard, then rightclick on another folder in Finder -> *services* -> *run the newly created script* to copy all symlinks from the clipboard to the other folder.

Comment: When you run the services script, do you want the symlinks copied to the new directory, or the contents of the folder it points to?

Comment: I want to copy the contents. E.g. copying the symlinks `.../some_dir_1` and `.../some_dir_2` should create the folders `some_dir_1` and `some_dir_2` with real copies of the files within the folders (inclusing referenced symlinks (resloved)).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a service like this:

[image]

`cp -R "$(/usr/local/bin/grealpath "$(osascript -e 'POSIX path of «class furl» of (the clipboard as record)')")" "$1"`

If the clipboard contains references to files, `«class furl» of (the clipboard as record)` returns a file object for the first file.

You might also use `cp -RH source target` instead of `` cp -R `grealpath source` target ``. If the symlink and its target have different names, it uses the name of the symlink though.

```
 -H    If the -R option is specified, symbolic links on the command line
       are followed.  (Symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal
       are not followed.)
```

Comment: I get an error running this code. Could you post the command as plain text? Maybe the error is because of the different quotation marks!?

Comment: I edited the answer. Did you copy a symlink to a folder in Finder before using the service? Is `grealpath` in `/usr/local/bin/grealpath`? Did you set "Pass input" to "as arguments"? Or if you tried to run the service from Automator, it doesn't work because there is no input.

Comment: Great, now it works with the first selection! Do you know what to change to make it work with multiple items?

Comment: No. If you copy multiple files, `«class furl» of (the clipboard as record)` only incudes the first file for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Applescript will treat a symlink like it's just another folder, so all you have to do is duplicate the contents.

```
Tell application "Finder"
    repeat with i from 1 to (count symlinks)
    set newFolder to make new folder at destFolder with properties {name:item i of symlinks)
    duplicate entire contents of item i of symlinks to newFolder
end
```